# Codeblocks: set files for stdin, stdout?

Tags: linux, codeblocks

How can i set files for stdin and stdout in codeblocks ide. I would be better if i can set them different for each build target. It may be linux only solution.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't.

Comment: It's been a few years since I used codeblocks, but I would expect you can customize the launch command to pipe the inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is not an IDE problem per se and you will need to solve this by coding.
But assuming you have two build targets in CodeBlocks named "Debug" and "Release".
Go to Project->Build Options->Compiler Settings->#defines
For Debug Target give a macro like : FOO_DEBUG and for Release: FOO_RELEASE

Finally somewhere in the initialization of your program differentiate between the different build targets like so:

```
#ifdef FOO_DEBUG
    freopen("in_d.log","r",stdin);
    freopen("out_d.log","w",stdout);
#else
    freopen("in_r.log","r",stdin);
    freopen("out_r.log","w",stdout);
#endif
```

Comment: It's IDE's problem too, in linux can be input or output redirected to another program. Then good IDE should be able to do it.